# AWS CodeDeploy Plugin Credentials Access Key/Secret Key set to Jenkins Admin U/P

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Trying to set up Jenkins on an EC2 with Code Pipeline. Using Jenkins v2.24

The Plugin has a captions that says:

*If keys are not specified, the plugin will use the default credentials providers and pull from one of: Environment variables, credentials profile, or IAM instance role. The latter is recommended if running on an EC2 instance.*

I have set up an Amazon IAM User/Role and the Instance Profile so that Jenkins can pick up that key automatically.

But when I go to Jenkins\Configure for the plugin, and I clear the Jenkins Admin user and password from the 
AWS Access Key and AWS Secret Key, then I save, the U/P automatically come back.

Being new to Jenkins, I'm not sure if I'm missing a setting somewhere else.

How can I get Jenkins to not automatically use the Jenkins Admin User and Password so I can leave the AWS Access Key and AWS Secret Key fields blank,
thus allowing Jenkins to pick up the keys from the profile instead??

Thanks!